# Launching VBA Applications blocks working with and opening other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I developed a vba application in excel for a company, They wants to leave it open the whole day until the end of work hours, while working normally on other excel workbooks.

The application is working just fine, no problem with the code.
My problem is that when the application is launched .. it blocks the other opened workbooks (I can't select cells or do anything).

And also If I try to open a sample excel file while the application is launched, it won't open.

(I tried with a simple userform and still the same problem, so the problem doesn't have anything to do with my application)

Is this something normal in Microsoft Excel, because I can't find anything on the net that is similar to my problem ?

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Should you talk about this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-add-ins-in-excel-0af570c4-5cf3-4fa9-9b88-403625a0b460?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US ?

Comment: Does your "application" has a form? If so, make sure its not a `Modal` form

Comment: Thank youuuu so much @Zac  .. I added `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` and worked just fine ..

Comment: No worries, glad it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as though you have a userform displayed modally (which is the default way of displaying a form). If you need to have the form displayed all the time you can display it modeless, but note that this does not work well with Excl's SDI implementation: you have to use Windows API calls to keep the form from being hidden. see http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/keepuserformontop01.asp

Alternatively you could change the design to use a ribbon command to display the form only when needed.

Comment: Thank you so much @Charles Williams .. I'll solve the problem temporarily with `UserForm1.Show vbModeless` .. I'll make sure to search about the Windows API calls ..

Comment: Modeless works fine with Excel 2010 : its only the way SDI got implement with XL 2013 thats a problem: and modeless works OK with Mac Excel 2016 SDI without the API calls.